# Ruby String to Date Conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date

I am faced with an issue in Ruby on Rails. I am looking to convert a string of format `Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 -0400 (EDT)` to a date object.

Is there anyway i could do this.

Here is what I've looked and tried at the following with no luck:

1. `Date.strptime(updated,"%a, %d %m %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")`
2. [Chronic Parser](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/)
3. [Ruby: convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720907/ruby-convert-string-to-date)
4. [Parsing date from text using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277504/parsing-date-from-text-using-ruby)

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

What is wrong with `Date.parse` method?

```
str = "Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 -0400 (EDT)"
date = Date.parse str
=> #<Date: 4910837/2,0,2299161>
puts date
2010-08-10
```

It seems to work.

The only problem here is time zone. If you want date in UTC time zone, then it is better to use `Time` object, suppose we have string:

```
str = "Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 +0400"
puts Date.parse str
2010-08-10
puts Date.parse(Time.parse(str).utc.to_s)
2010-08-09
```

I couldn't find simpler method to convert `Time` to `Date`.

Comment: Thanks Klew and Ryan. This worked like a charm. I was aware of Date.parse, but hadn't used it. This is a learning for me.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 has Time#to_date to convert Time to date.

Comment: what if I need it in day/month/year eg: 16/10/2015?

Answer (score 18):

```
Date.strptime(updated,"%a, %d %m %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Should be:

```
Date.strptime(updated, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
str = "Tue, 10 Aug 2010 01:20:19 -0400 (EDT)"
str.to_date
=> Tue, 10 Aug 2010
```

Comment: this is a Rails thing, not a Ruby thing I think

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://rubygems.org/gems/dates_from_string:

Find date in structure:

```
text = "get car from repair 2015-02-02 23:00:10"
dates_from_string = DatesFromString.new
dates_from_string.find_date(text)

=> ["2015-02-02 23:00:10"]
```