# How do I extract all dates from a text?

Tags: ruby

I've found many ways to extract one date from a text,
for instance: "[Parsing date from text using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277504/parsing-date-from-text-using-ruby)".

But in my case, I've got many dates:

```
lorem ipsum 01/01/2014 lorem ipsum 02/02/2014 lorem ipsum 03/03/2014
```

I would like to output:

```
01/01/2014
02/02/2014
03/03/2014
```

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex to scan for `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}` and then collect the results into an array or simply print them as they're matched.

```
File.open("your_file.txt").read().scan(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)
```

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/8dfd6).